# MySQL repeat delete autonomously

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo, synology

I'm having a really annoying problem with a database system i'm building. It's quite hard to explain, but i'll try.
The system is for documenting workshop repairs.
It's build using PHP, MySQL, Javascript and Jquery.
Running on a Synology DS212+ with DSM 5.1
I have 3 files in question:

```
vr_edit.php
vr_edit_save.php
vr_edit_cancel.php
```

When starting a repport this file is generating a new record:

```
vr_edit.php?edit=new
    $sth = $conn->prepare($sql_str);
    $sth->execute($dataArr);
    $vrnr = $conn->lastInsertId();
    header("Location: ".$goto);
```

and redirects the browser to:

```
vr_edit.php?edit=45000
```

vr_edit then reads the record and shows a form for editing it. This is send to vr_edit_save which obviously saves the data.

In the edit form you have the posibillty to cancel the report:

```
<button style="width: 165px; margin-top: 8px;" type="button" id="anullerknap" onclick="location.href=('vr_edit_cancel.php?vrnr=46008&setid=46008&cancelReturn=%2FVR3000-TEST%2Findex.php'); return false;"><u>A</u>nullér</button>

vr_edit_cancel.php:

    $sql_str = "DELETE FROM `v_rapporter` WHERE vrnr = ".$vrnr." AND status = 'oprettet' LIMIT 1";
    $sth = $conn->prepare($sql_str);
    $sth->execute();
    $sql_str = "ALTER TABLE `v_rapporter` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;";
    $sth = $conn->prepare($sql_str);
    $sth->execute();
    unset($sth);
    unset($sql_str);
    unset($conn);
    header("Location: ".$goTo);//This points to old location before creating new record
```

All this works well, but now the problem kick in. When i create a new repport after i have deleted one. It gets the same id (vrnr) as the deleted one, and that fine, it's supposed to.
But suddently it deletes the record again without any script being called. And it's like it is tottally random. Sometimes it does that in a few seconds, sometimes after a minute, and sometimes not at all.

I have worked hard for a solution but with no result.
I made a log system, a filebased and a databasebased one. But when i turn on the logging system, the error magically disapears.

I'm lost in this, can anyone help me?

Comment: You should not use GET requests to delete or modify data, always use POST. That will avoid problems with browsers trying to fetch links to speed up browsing, accidental reloads, etc.

Comment: @jeroen - Thank you for your comment. Do you think this is whats causing this? It's doesn't happen if i close the browser and open the page again. And it only deletes record-id's which have been deleted before. So if it is the browser doing this, it only does it, when it has done it before.

Comment: It certainly looks like it; it sounds like your browser is reloading previously loaded pages.

Comment: @jeroen It does it both with chrome and IE. Anyway your suggestion worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to use POST instead of GET as @jeroen suggested in the comments.